# Cloud Providers supported by docusign- does it support AWS?

Tags: docusignapi

Has someone done any integration with docusign with other cloud providers like AWS? I found their support page for cloud providers but looks like they only support the following: If any one has done this integration it would be great if you could let me know.

The following providers are supported:
Google Drive
Dropbox
Box
OneDrive (Personal and Business)

https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-give-docusign-access-to-your-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to consumer cloud providers that have nothing to do with API or coding. 
I'm not sure if AWS has a consumer cloud option where anyone can share files, if they do, you can submit a request for this feature, which is not currently available, by sending an email to feedback@docusign.com.

If you are talking about using AWS as a developer, yes, it is supported, you can host your app on any cloud provider and use DocuSign APIs.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My use case was specifically to use docuSign API's to fetch a file from an s3 bucket for example. Based on your answer it looks like its possible?

Comment: yes, it is, but in your question you referred to something different. You can get the document from anywhere if using the API. There are no limits. You would have to figure out separately how to get bits from AWS S3 bucket, that's not something DocuSign does for you though.